# How to backup dir structure ignoring files & dirs without read permission

Tags: permissions, files, backup, tar

Any ideas how to back up a directory structure for which there are some files and/or directories for which you do not have permission to read? I'd like to just ignore those, without backup (tar? jar?) crashing.

Answer (score 11):

Gnu tar has an option `--ignore-failed-read` which does just that.

If you aren't using GNU tar, you can either generate a list of files to back up, or a list of files to exclude. GNU find has a `-readable` predicate that tests whether you have read permission on the file. With other versions of find, to stay with `find` alone, you'll need to approximate this with file permissions (`-perm`) and ownership (`-user`, `group`), which makes it difficult to cope with groups, ACLs, etc. You can get a precise test by calling the external program or shell builtin `test`. Here's an example assuming your `tar` has the option `-X` to read a newline-separated list of file names to exclude (file names containing newlines are skipped, to avoid parsing problems):

```
find . ! -name '*
*' -exec sh -c 'for x; do [ -r "$x" ] || printf "%s\\n" "$x"; done' _ {} |
tar -cf backup.tar -X - .
```

Comment: Worked perfectly first time with --ignore-failed-read, many thanks. System was Red Hat so GNU tar was in place.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have newlines in the paths then you can do this:

```
find . -type f -readable -print | tar cf test.tar -T -
```

This may be limited to GNU `find` and `tar` and may not work with certain file systems (NFS, FUSE). If there are or may be newlines then use `-print0` instead of `-print` for `find` and add `--null` for `tar`.